# How to add items to a DataGridView ComboBoxColumn?

Tags: c#, datagridviewcombobox

I'm having a problem with filling a `comboxcolumn` in a datagrid view. Here is a brief description of my problem.

I've a combo column in datagrid view named as `dgvRightsColumn` and table in SQL named as Rights. I want to fill this combobox of dagaridview with the RightsNames in Rights Table.

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dgvRightsColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

SqlCommand fillRights = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Rights]", sqlConnection);
SqlDataReader readerRights = fillRights.ExecuteReader();

while (readerRights.Read())
{
    dgvRightsColumn.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(readerRights["RightName"]));
}

readerRights.Close();
```

Comment: What is the issue you are having?

Comment: is it winform? or Webform?

Comment: thanks for replying @rae1n. This code is not adding items in combo box. When I run this code. Combobox is still blank

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi it is a winform in C#

Comment: It looks as if you are using a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn without a DataGridView. Your combo instance is created and then disappears in the GC. BTW: are you looking for a ComboBox?
Take a look at data binding mechanisms. They make life much easier.

Comment: @TomB, I do have a DataGridView named as dgvTasksRights and in this GridView I've Four column, 1st Task Id, 2nd Task Name, 3rd Rights (Combobox Column), 4th CheckboxColumn. I'm just trying to assign a task to a specific user with specific permissions (Rights, that will be selected from combobox and Tasks will be assigned by checkbox.checked). I want to assign multiple tasks to one user, for this reason I've made gridview that contains the list of tasks. It also contains a combobx in each row to assign different rights on different tasks and a checkbox to select a particular task.

Comment: @AzeemKhalid: you need to cast the required column from `DataGridview` to the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` , check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem :** you are just creating the object for `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` but not specifying the actual column to be considered from Gridview as ComboBox that is 3rd column.

**Solution :** you need to `cast` the required column from `DataGridview` to the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to insert the Items.

**Replace This :**

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dgvRightsColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
```

**With This:**

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dgvRightsColumn= dgvTasksRights.Columns[2] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
```

**Note :** You are not opening the `SqlConnectoion` Object  `sqlConnection` before Executing the `ExecuteReader` command.You need to open it as below :

```
sqlConnection.Open();
```

**Complete Code:**
Try This :

```
SqlCommand fillRights = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Rights]", sqlConnection);
sqlConnection.Open();
SqlDataReader readerRights = fillRights.ExecuteReader();

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dgvRightsColumn= dgvTasksRights.Columns[2] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
while (readerRights.Read())
{                
 dgvRightsColumn.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(readerRights["RightName"]));
}  
readerRights.Close();
```

Comment: bundle of thank... I got my mistake. Now it is working. By the way I just posted selected code where I was getting problem SqlConnection was already open :-p. Bundle of thanks again. :-)

Comment: @AzeemKhalid: You are welcome :) , I'm glad to be Help of you.Have a nice day.

Comment: can I have a chat with you...?